# Does a class have to be an object, can it be an action?

Tags: python, class, init

I'm writing some kind of text based game and I have some thoughts about classes and initializing and so on.

I know that I can use classes if I'm making a "blueprint" for a thing. I'm a bit unsure about how to use `__init__`, although I think I can figure that out by just testing. What I wonder is, can I use classes for actions? Like, say I want to make a class for at the gym, a training program, maybe. I would need a function for every kind of exercise (3 kinds in this case) as they are really different; swimming and running, weight lifting and playing tennis. So you can choose what exercise you want to do and then you will do that and then maybe you can do one more and then you're done or something.

And the reason I want to use a class is that I would have variables for for example condition, strength and tech and I would be able to use these variables while I'm at the gym but they won't change. And I would be able to go to othe gym much simpler. Can I use a class for that and then call the functions by simply just use `class.function()`?

Also, do you always need to have `__init__`? Because I see no reason to use it in this case, right?

I hope you understand what I'm asking, if you don't get it I can try explaining a bit more.

Comment: Why not make action a class, and then create instances of it for swimming, running, etc.?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because... Well, all right, I guess I could do that. Still, I wonder if it would work and if `__init__` is important.

Comment: `__init__` is the function called when you create an instance of the class. It's there you will set the action type and other parameters if needed.

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux Oh well, I think all I needed was someone telling me  to "set the _action_ type and other parameters"... Now I know how to solve my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am not quite familiar with Python, I think I can provide some general OOP advice.

First of all, Classes are something like "real-life object abstractions", so it seems a bit odd to me to make a class to represent an action.

Now, objects, which are instances of classes, have two principal characteristics:

- An object has ***attributes*** that represent the state of the particular object at a given time.
- An object has ***methods*** that represent the actions it can take

So, let's say you have a class `Athlete`, and it has attributes like `strength`, `skill`, `weight`, etcetera. These are general attributes, which any athlete has.

But now you need that athlete to be a runner, and you need to set aditional attributes for a runner (let's say `specialty`, which can take different values if the runner is a sprinter or a marathon runner, for example). Instead of writing an entire new class for a runner, which, after all, *is* an athlete, you can merely write a **Sub class** of athlete, and add all the specific parameters related to a `Runner`.

---

So, time to code:

```
class Athlete:
    def __init__(self, strength, skill, weight):
        self.strength = strength
        self.skill = skill
        self.weight = weight
    def anAthleteMethod(self):
        pass

class Runner(Athlete):
    def __init__(self, strenght, skill, weight, specialty):
        super(Athlete, self, strenght, skill, weight)
        self.specialty = specialty
    def run(self):
        pass
```

So, finally, answering your question:

- From my particular point of view, you can't write a class to perform an action... but you can create subclasses to any particular class that perform the appropriate actions
- **A workaround:** You could write a class `Sport` that could take an athlete and make it perform whatever you want him to do

Comment: Just like `__init__` Python classes can have a `__call__` which then makes instances of that class callable.  So one could make a class to represent actions.  Overall a good explanation, though.